# python photogrammetry toolbox GUI for windows

Tags: python, windows, photogrammetry

I recently studied photogrammetry and am interested in using the python photogrammetry toolbox, however, I'm working on windows 10 64 bit and I don't know how to install the PPT in windows. The only related PPT GUI with Windows I can find is in  http://arc-team-open-research.blogspot.com/2011/09/python-photogrammetry-toolbox-for.html

Does anyone know any tutorial on how to install on Windows 10?

edit: python 3.6 64bit installed already on my pc (beginner at python though)

Comment: Do you have an installer for that software?

Comment: yes i have copy the file from https://code.google.com/archive/p/osm-bundler/downloads and i don't know what is the next step

Comment: I downloaded & extracted the files to a `virtualenv` installed `pip` and `osm-bundler-pmvs2-cmvs-full-32-64` runs fine with Python2. It created a directory of results. I'm running Windows 10 64-bit also. Have you read the `ReadMe.txt` in `osm-bundler-pmvs2-cmvs-full-32-64` directory. It explains how to run the scripts. There are 4 featured programs on that webpage. Which are you trying to run?

Comment: Your latest edit you mentions you are working with `python 3.6 64bit`. The main problem you might encounter is the scripts won't work with any version of Python3 --- the code is so old that it only works with Python2.

Comment: Thank you so much @davedwards for taking time running the script and check. Yes at the moment I'm working with Python 3, later I will try to use other PC that has Python2 and see if I can run the script

Comment: Sure no problem, it's is kind of confusing at first to get the environment setup, but I'm sure you'll get it working. If you need any help or suggestions, leave another comment.